# Only one of 4 DOS Borland Dbase 300mb dbf files errors using python dbfread lib after many minutes with a non ascii character

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile, dbf, dbase

I read 4 files fine but one one I got this error using the code below:
dbfread is giving this error:

`return decode_text(text, self.encoding, errors=self.char_decode_errors) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 11: ordin`

loading a 300mb file. According to google it needs the character format. I have 4 dbf files all were loaded with dbfread except this one.

```
from dbfread import DBF

    def load_data_from_dbf(self, num=10000):
        records = list(DBF(self.dbf_file_path))[-num:]
        with self.data_lock:
            self.df = pd.DataFrame(records)
            self.index1DF = self.df.set_index([self.indexf[0]])
            if len(self.indexf) > 1:
                self.index2DF = self.df.set_index([self.indexf[1]])
```

Comment: That's not a *DOS* file. DOS is an old operating system, not a database or application. `dbf` is the file extension for dBase or Clipper database files, also very old. Where did these files come from?

Comment: Does the file you're trying to read contain non-English characters? `ascii` refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII range and can fail to handle even some English words like `naïve`. Try using `DBF(self.dbf_file_path,encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: DOS files do not have UTF-8 encoding. they are some weird dos/windows encoding. geopandas works. I dont need another solution!

Comment: I didn't downvote. Anyone who's worked with dbf files or Shapefiles would tell you them same

Comment: It's not a DOS file, and *all* data uses one encoding or another. The only reason geopandas seemd to work is because it used a different default encoding than `DBF`, perhaps UTF8 or Latin1. This page has an encoding too, it's UTF-8.

Answer (score -3):

After searching and trying geopandas it resolved the issue. THis is because "The format drivers will attempt to detect the encoding of your data, but may fail. In this case, the proper encoding can be specified explicitly by using the encoding keyword parameter, e.g. encoding='utf-8'." Geopandas derives the encoding while dbfread does not. So this answer works. It does add a 'geometry' which can be ignored.

here is a code snippet:

```
import geopandas as gpd
def load_data_from_dbf(self, num=100000):
    tempdf = gpd.read_file(self.dbf_file_path)
    indexDF = tempdf.tail(num).set_index([self.indexf[0]])
    with self.data_lock:
        self.df = tempdf
        self.index1DF = indexDF
        if len(self.indexf) > 1:
            self.index2DF = self.df.set_index([self.indexf[1]])
```

Comment: Those are dBase database files, not text. Unicode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: so where did the error originate in DBF() dbfread. Why does geopandas read the same file with no error.

Comment: You tried to read a binary database file as if it was text. That's the same as trying to read a PNG or JPG as if it was text. dBase was a *very* popular product in the 1980s, 1990s. The only reason geopandas works with this is that ESRI's Shapefiles used it in the early 2000s to store non-spatial data along with spatial features.

Comment: You are too assuming. The same code works on three different dbf files . Only one did not work and I used geopandas on that one as I needed DataFrames!

Comment: This will definitely help another user who gets the answer use dbfread from ChatGPT

Comment: No, I actually worked with both dBase and spatial data in the past. `ascii` refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII which can't even handle English words like `naïve`. If that's the case, passing the correct `encoding` parameter to `DBF` will work. Both DBF and GeoPandas try to guess the database's encoding but fall back to different defaults if that fails

Comment: From the [Geopandas.read_file](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.read_file.html) docs: `The format drivers will attempt to detect the encoding of your data, but may fail. In this case, the proper encoding can be specified explicitly by using the encoding keyword parameter, e.g. encoding='utf-8'.`